# Send Return Key To Excel Formula Bar Using WinAPI

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to copy text to the clipboard then paste into excel while keeping all the formatting.

The only way I have found to stop excel from spreading the text across many cells and keep formatting like bullet points etc is after copying to the clipboard, to paste it directly into the formula bar.

### How I'm attempting it:

I'm using Win API to get the handle of the formula bar.

Then sending a WM_PASTE message to the window to paste what's on the clipboard.

Then sending a WM_SETFOCUS message to the window ready to receive the return key.

Then sending a WM_KEYDOWN message for the return key.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow _
    Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx _
    Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hwndParent As Long, _
    ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, _
    ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage _
    Lib "user32.dll" _
    Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal Msg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByRef lParam As Any) _
    As Long
    
Declare Function PostMessage _
    Lib "user32" _
    Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) As Long

Declare Function SetForegroundWindow _
    Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
                   
Private Const WM_CUT As Long = &H300
Private Const WM_COPY As Long = &H301
Private Const WM_PASTE As Long = &H302
Private Const WM_CLEAR As Long = &H303
Private Const WM_UNDO As Long = &H304
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN  As Long = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP  As Long = &H101
Private Const VK_F5  As Long = &H74
Private Const VK_RETURN  As Long = &HD
Private Const WM_CHAR  As Long = &H102
Private Const WM_SETFOCUS  As Long = &H7
Private Const WM_KILLFOCUS  As Long = &H8
Private Const WM_IME_SETCONTEXT  As Long = &H281

Public Sub pasteClipboard()
    hwndMain = Application.hWnd: Debug.Print hwndMain
    hwndFormulaBar = FindWindowEx(Application.hWnd, ByVal 0&, "EXCEL<", vbNullString): Debug.Print hwndFormulaBar
    hwndDesk = FindWindowEx(Application.hWnd, ByVal 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString): Debug.Print hwndDesk
    hwndSheet = FindWindowEx(hwndDesk, ByVal 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString): Debug.Print hwndSheet

    RetVal = SendMessage(hwndFormulaBar, WM_PASTE, 0, ByVal 0)
    Debug.Print SendMessage(hwndFormulaBar, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print SendMessage(hwndFormulaBar, WM_IME_SETCONTEXT, &H0, &H0)
    Debug.Print SendMessage(hwndFormulaBar, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, &H0)
End Sub
```

### The Problem:

This all works up until when I send the return key to finish editing the cell which is what I'd like to happen. Instead it puts a carriage return in the text box which makes a lot of sense but not the result I wanted.

I've looked at the formula window with Spy++ and watched what happens when I type something in the window and hit return - when the return key is hit it finishes editing the cell.

[image]

The only two commands I'm not using that show up in Spy++ are WM_IME_SETCONTEXT and WM_IME_NOTIFY but in all honesty I'm not sure what these two commands do.

I tried using the WM_IME_SETCONTEXT above thinking I may have to change it before sending the return key but the results didn't change.

### Any solutions?

If anyone can point me in the right direction of how to send a message that will finish editing the cell (doesn't have to be the return key, that was just my first thought) that would be great.

Many Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this may help, but TAB key also finishes editing cell and skips to next one. Would that help?

Comment: Excel exposes an automation interface, so that you don't have to fiddle with faking input. See [Excel VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel) as a starting point.

Comment: IME is "foreign character" input, ignore these messages.

Comment: `The only way I have found to stop excel from spreading the text across many cells and keep formatting like bullet points etc is after copying to the clipboard, to paste it directly into the formula bar.` I'd rather to record a macro with desired actions (options when pasting text and so on, and the adopt generated VBA code for my needs)

Comment: Refer to [Application.SendKeys method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments.

@Rita Han - MSFT The application.SendKeys worked as long as the focus was not the VBE window which is great!